# Oracle sqlplus comments

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus

Why does the following insert statement not work when executed like `sqlplus <connect> @file`

```
INSERT INTO abc ( a
                 ,b
                 ,c)
         VALUES ( '1' --a
                 ,'2' --b
                 ,'3'); --c
```

but it works without the comments i.e

```
INSERT INTO abc ( a
                 ,b
                 ,c)
         VALUES ( '1'
                 ,'2'
                 ,'3');
```

Does sqlplus flatten the file i.e execute the whole thing on a single line? which might result in rest of the line getting commented out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fist `insert` statement *didn't work* only because of the last comment `--c` you've placed after the statement terminator. SQL*Plus doesn't allow any text after a statement terminator (';' semicolon in this case). So this version of your first `insert` statement will be executed successfully:

```
INSERT INTO abc ( a
                 ,b
                 ,c)
         VALUES ( '1' --a
                 ,'2' --b
                 ,'3');
```

So will this one:

```
INSERT INTO abc ( a
                 ,b
                 ,c)
         VALUES ( '1' --a
                 ,'2' --b
                 ,'3') --c;
```

Comment: still a tool full of bugs, not recommended for industry

Answer (score 1):

The fact that SQL*PLUS permits the second one to operate is bizarre.  A GUI tool considers the whole thing a comment, with the effect that the ; is not really terminating the SQL.